# Getting null pointer exception, new to Java

Tags: java

Getting a Null Pointer Exception that I dont understand since Im new to java.

```
package com.atm;

import com.atm.IUserAction.ActionType;

/**
 * The ATM implementation class.
 * 
 * @author mshields
 * 
 */
public class AtmImpl {

    private static final IAtmHelper ATM =  AtmUtils.getAtmHelper();

    /**
     * This method is invoked when a bank card is inserted into the ATM. The card
     * is ejected immediately upon completion of this method, which represents the
     * user's ATM session.
     * 
     * @param args
     *          the bank card number is the only argument.
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        IUserAction pinResponse = ATM.getUserResponse("Please enter your 4-digit PIN.", ActionType.STRING);
```

the last line is where im getting the error. I thought it is initialized when I said

```
private static final IAtmHelper ATM =  AtmUtils.getAtmHelper();
```

the IAtmHelper is basically empty:

```
public class AtmUtils {

    public static IAtmHelper getAtmHelper() 
    {
        // this dummy impl is just included to satisfy compile-time errors
        return null;
    }
}
```

here is the top of the ATMHelper class that is used:

```
package com.atm;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

import com.atm.IUserAction.ActionType;

/**
 * Interface that defines ATM utility methods.
 * 
 * @author mshields
 * 
 */
public interface IAtmHelper {
```

here is the function

```
public IUserAction getUserResponse(String argMessage,
            ActionType... argValidActionTypes);
```

they dont really do anthing since this isnt a real porject, but more like a test. I understand how to do all of it basically, but i cant get around this null pointer in the beginning of the main.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing a **null pointer** because you are returning a **null** object:

```
public static IAtmHelper getAtmHelper() 
    {
        // this dummy impl is just included to satisfy compile-time errors
        return null; // <-- I am causing your NPE
    }
```

You probably want to return an instance of an `AtmHelper` from within the function like this:

```
  public static IAtmHelper getAtmHelper() 
    {
        return new AtmHelper();
    }
```

Comment: It gives me the error "Cannot instantiate type IATMHelper

Comment: @user3571618 right you can't instantiate interfaces.

Comment: I tried to implement it, but it didnt work. unless im doing it wrong... :( 
How do I go about doing this, ive tried so many things!

Comment: @user3571618 that doesn't mean much, what did you "implement", you aren't really giving us any information to work from.

Comment: I tried something like 
    `public class ATmUtils implements IAtmHelper`

but it didnt work. It seems like i need to create an instance of IAtmHelper, but i dont know how to

Comment: also, IAtmHelper is a interface, not a class. idk if that helps